# Conditional serialization based off of value of attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, active-model-serializers

I am trying to limit which children get displayed in the json response at the serializer level. If a currency is marked as 'active' the currency should be included in the payload for Merchant. If the currency is 'inactive' the GET on merchant should not be included.

rails, 4.2.5
active_model_serializers, ~>0.10.0.rc3

**Serializers**

```
class MerchantSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :merchant_name, :merchant_type, :currencies
  has_many :merchant_currency_maps
end

class MerchantCurrencyMapSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :currency, :b4flight_id, :aht_account_id, :created_at, :updated_at, :guess_merchant 
end
```

**What I've tried**

I've tried making `include_currency_maps` methods [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594472/use-attribute-with-condition-in-activemodel-serializer)but to no avail.
And creating custom attributes shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29705802/conditional-attributes-in-active-model-serializers). But I am still struggling to grasp how this can/should be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want `has_many :merchant_currency_maps` to only include currency maps that are active, right?  You could try an override in your `MerchantSerializer`:

```
def merchant_currency_maps
  object.merchant_currency_maps.where(active: true)
end
```

Comment: That is slick. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using this will allow rails to cache your data better I believe:

```
has_many :merchant_currency_maps, -> { where(active: true) }
```

Or do this

```
has_many :active_merchant_currency_maps,   -> { where(active: true) }
has_many :merchant_currency_maps 
has_many :inactive_merchant_currency_maps, -> { where(active: false) }
```

Each would be cached separately.  The worry with this is each of the 3 arrays have different objects and can become out of sync unless you have rails configured to sync them up.